# Why HTML5 symbols shows different colors and sizes in same browser

Tags: css, html, unicode

I'm using special characters such as `(chart increasing)`,`(chart decreasing)` in a web page.

When displayed in my pc, with firefox 54.0.1 (64-bits), they appear as grey square and yellow line:

[image]

When diplayed in another pc, with same firefox version, same OS version, they appear as white square and green/red lines. and different size:

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-OnTDmSsAC4Y/WV97nlgz0-I/AAAAAAAABsA/CC5htffesDkImzVMJBcm-aZqo1DaWbJ3gCL0BGAYYCw/h23/2017-07-07.png]

I understand they could look different if i where using different browsers, but why does it happen in the same browsers, different pc?

Contents of `%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\fonts` are the same in both.

Comment: In short: because they are text, the browser has a default font and some fonts are coloured.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález oh tell me more about "default" font https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgEWX.gif

Comment: @HernánEche [Emojis put the fun on Unicode](https://el-tramo.be/blog/emoji-combinations/).

Answer (score 2):

You are using emojis and there is no standard rendering for them. You can see the different renderings of them here: http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html (for reference you seem to be using `chart increasing` and `chart decreasing`)

The only way you could force a constant look is maybe if you specified your own font to use and the font has full emoji support.

Comment: what i don't understand it why the SAME browser version, on the SAME Windows version, shows the characters different. "no standard rendering for them" doesn't mean firefox will use something as "randomDisplay(character)"

Comment: @ndelucca I think your doubts come because you think they are symbols or images. It's just text and nothing but text, but they're rare characters that 99% of fonts do not include so it's not like assuming that the browser will use the *Times New Roman* that comes with Windows.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i do understand it's just text, maybe what i don't understand is something even more basic.... how do the same browser version, with same windows, installed the same way, with almost no differences during setup (you never have identical systems, but its close enough), have different default fonts...

Comment: @ndelucca Oh, right, now I think I fully understand your question. Could you please compare the contents of the `%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\fonts` in both computers?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i've checked the file in that path, they seem to be identical, but just in case i copied the one in the other pc and overwritten the file in my pc, the problem persists.

Comment: @ndelucca I'm out of ideas. Question proved to be much more interesting that it looked at first sight.